# Add text to UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have a core data model that contain string, i want that when i select a row of the table contain the string of the core data i see in other view the text printed in a UIImage, i have done all, and i found this method: http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx, but when i print the test, he print it in the left bottm corner of the UIImageView...in the (0,0) point, how i can make print the text in the middle of the image and justified automatically the text?, because the image is a triangle, and i want the text stay in the triangle, how i can do it? or there is another method?...thanks!

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to use a `UIImageView` and a separate `UILabel1 to display the text. I think you would have more control over the positioning.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i put a UILabel but i have a problem, when i write in the UILabel the text it's write in the middle of the box of the UILabel and not in the top, my text change some time 1 row some time 2 sometime 3 and i want to start write te text at the top of the box, how i can do it?

Comment: Unforutnately the `UILabel` view always aligns it's contents to the middle. In order to override this behavior, you must manually resize the view. [Here](http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/blog/uilabel-align-top) is a quick snippet with the code you need. You can find more help by googling "UILabel vertical align".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)myImage {
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promoicon.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);
[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height)];
UITextView *myText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
myText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:15.0f];
myText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myText.text = NSLocalizedString(@"My Text", @"");
myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [myText.text sizeWithFont:myText.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
myText.frame = CGRectMake((myImage.size.width / 2) - (expectedLabelSize.width / 2),(myImage.size.height / 2) - (expectedLabelSize.height / 2),myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[myText.text drawInRect:myText.frame withFont:myText.font];
UIImage *myNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return myNewImage; }
```